# Задать формат времени в часах

Tags: java, android, время

Пишу приложения для часов.

Есть перемененные `int hour=1` и `int min=9`.

Как правильно переводить такие числа к "01" и "09" в `int` или сразу `string` для последующей отправки по bluetooth.

Comment: А вы как приводите их к `String`? И почему считаете, что делаете это неправильно?

Comment: у меня есть вариант перевести число  в string, затем if (string.lench==1) {sting ="0"+ string  }. И меня интересует вопрос есть ли более правильный способ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если абстрагироваться от того, что это часы и минуты, то можно представить это как форматирование вывода числа.

В этом случае можно воспользоваться методом [String.format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)):

```
String result = String.format("%02d", hour);
```

---

Решение "в лоб" для конкретной ситуации из вопроса, на мой взгляд, тоже вполне имеет право на жизнь, потому что оно понятное, короткое и работает как минимум не медленно:

```
String result = hour < 10 ? "0" + hour : "" + hour;
```

При использовании старой версии Java оно вообще становится основным. Для Android столь старые версии неактуальны, но всё же.

Answer (score 3):

Используйте `SimpleDateFormat`:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
String hours = new SimpleDateFormat("HH").format(calendar.getTime()); 
String minutes = new SimpleDateFormat("mm").format(calendar.getTime());
```

"HH" (и "mm") отвечают за то, чтобы числа отображались двузначные (даже если они меньше 10).

Посмотрите, [здесь](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat) более подробно. Там есть и другие форматы отображения дат.